# How I can validate config for electron-builder?

Tags: electron-builder

For example, I have config in `package.json`

```
"build": {
  "win": {
    "target": [
      {
        "target": "nsis",
        "arch": [
          "x64",
          "ia32"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I want validate this before start build process or CI/CD pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Example](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/master/packages/app-builder-lib/src/util/config.ts) of how electron-builder check config.

Then we can try to use the same method and tools - [@develar/schema-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@develar/schema-utils) and scheme which uses electron-builder for validation

```js
// validate.js
const validate = require('@develar/schema-utils');

const  schema = require('./schemas/schema.json');

const options = {
  "win": {
    "target": [
      {
        "target": "nsis",
        "arch": [
          "x64",
          "ia32"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};

const configuration = {
name: 'electron-builder'
};

try {

  validate(schema, options, configuration);
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message)
}
```

If we execute command:

```
node validate.js
```

We have not something input.

But if we use wrong config. For example,

```js
const options = {
  "win": {
    "target": [
      {
        "target": ["nsis"],
        "arch": [
          "x64",
          "ia32"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

The output of the command will be:

```
Invalid configuration object. electron-builder has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.win.target[0].target should be a string.
   -> The target name. e.g. `snap`.
```